# Add multi level column to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, multi-level

At the beginning, I'd like to add a multilevel column to an empty dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"nodes": list(range(1, 5, 2))})
df.set_index("nodes", inplace=True)
```

So this is the dataframe to start with (still empty):

```
>>> df
nodes
1
3
```

Now I'd like to a first multilevel column.

I tried the following:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(df.index, [1,2])), orient="index",
    columns=["value"])

df = pd.concat([new_df], axis=1, keys=["test"])
```

Now the dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
>>> df
         test
        value
1           1
3           2
```

To add another column, i've done something similar.

```
new_df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(df.index, [3,4])), orient="index",
    columns=[("test2", "value2")])

df = pd.concat([df, new_df2], axis=1)
df.index.name = "nodes"
```

So the desired dataframe looks like this:

```
>>> df
          test       test2
nodes    value      value2
1            1           3
3            2           4
```

This way of adding multilevel columns seems a bit strange. Is there a better way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Create a MultIndex on the columns by storing your DataFrames in a `dict` then concat along `axis=1`. The keys of the dict become levels of the column MultiIndex (if you use tuples it adds multiple levels depending on the length, scalar keys add a single level) and the DataFrame columns stay as is. Alignment is enforced on the row Index.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {}
d[('foo', 'bar')] = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1,2,3]}).rename_axis(index='nodes')
d[('foo2', 'bar2')] = pd.DataFrame({'val2': [4,5,6]}).rename_axis(index='nodes')
d[('foo2', 'bar1')] = pd.DataFrame({'val2': [7,8,9]}).rename_axis(index='nodes')

pd.concat(d, axis=1)
```

---

```
      foo foo2     
      bar bar2 bar1
      val val2 val2
nodes              
0       1    4    7
1       2    5    8
2       3    6    9
```

Comment: I need to update the dataframe in the course of time (not all columns at once). But i also need to have dataframe after each added column. And unfortunately i also need the index like above. I this also possible?