# How to Add another level of column to an existing multi-level column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   x   
   A  B
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```

When I want to add another level to the multi-level columns using the following code

```
x.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['D'], x.columns])
```

it gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adel.moustafa\DashBoard\main.py", line 262, in <module>
    calculate_yield()
  File "C:\Users\adel.moustafa\DashBoard\main.py", line 204, in calculate_yield
    Analyzer.yield_analyzer_by(yield_data, all_data_df, df_info['P/F Criteria'], 'batch')
  File "C:\Users\adel.moustafa\DashBoard\Modules\Analyzer.py", line 163, in yield_analyzer_by
    x.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['D'], x.columns])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 621, in from_product
    codes, levels = factorize_from_iterables(iterables)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py", line 2881, in factorize_from_iterables
    codes, categories = zip(*(factorize_from_iterable(it) for it in iterables))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py", line 2881, in <genexpr>
    codes, categories = zip(*(factorize_from_iterable(it) for it in iterables))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py", line 2854, in factorize_from_iterable
    cat = Categorical(values, ordered=False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py", line 451, in __init__
    dtype = CategoricalDtype(categories, dtype.ordered)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\dtypes.py", line 183, in __init__
    self._finalize(categories, ordered, fastpath=False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\dtypes.py", line 337, in _finalize
    categories = self.validate_categories(categories, fastpath=fastpath)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\dtypes.py", line 530, in validate_categories
    if categories.hasnans:
  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 37, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2681, in hasnans
    return bool(self._isnan.any())
  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 37, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2666, in _isnan
    return isna(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\missing.py", line 144, in isna
    return _isna(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\missing.py", line 169, in _isna
    raise NotImplementedError("isna is not defined for MultiIndex")
NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex
```

I have checked that there is no Na values in my column nor its values, I have also looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320329/add-multi-level-column-to-dataframe) and [this post](https://fixexception.com/pandas/isna-is-not-defined-for-multiindex/) and finally [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041624/seaborn-barplot-isna-is-not-defined-for-multiindex) but with no results

here is reproducible code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x'], ['A', 'B']]))
x.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['D'], x.columns])
```

can any one point to what is wrong and how fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
 x.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['D'], *x.columns.levels])
```

where `x.columns.levels` gives you a Frozenlist of columns that form the MultiIndex.

And then you have to unpack the list using `*` in order to pass list of lists to `from_product`.

Answer (score 0):

You can denote a multi-level column with a tuple. For instance:

```py
x[('y', 'C')] = x[('x', 'A')] + 1
x[('x', 'D')] = 0

>>> x
   x     y  x
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  1  0
1  2  3  3  0
2  4  5  5  0
3  6  7  7  0
4  8  9  9  0
```

And, of course, you can sort the columns:

```py
x = x.sort_index(axis=1)

>>> x
   x        y
   A  B  D  C
0  0  1  0  1
1  2  3  0  3
2  4  5  0  5
3  6  7  0  7
4  8  9  0  9
```